# How can I capture detected image by Yolov4

Tags: python, object-detection, video-capture, screen-capture, yolov4

I want to capture the box recognized while using YOLOv4 webcam recognition.

So i used this code.

```
import cv2
import detect as dt
from darknet import Darknet
from PIL import Image
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
success, image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
m = Darknet('darknet/data/yolo-obj.cfg')
m.load_weights('darknet/backup/yolo-obj_30000.weights')
use_cuda = 1
m.cuda()
while success:
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    im_pil = Image.fromarray(image)
    im_pil = im_pil.resize((m.width, m.height))
    boxes = dt.do_detect(m, im_pil, 0.5, 0.4, use_cuda)
    result = open('Desktop/captureyolobox/capture%04d.jpg'%(count), 'w')
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        result.write(boxes[i])
    count = count + 1
    success, image = vidcap.read()
    result.close()
```

I've encountered this problem. I surfed the web to solve the problem, but I couldn't find it. Can you help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "yoloshort.py", line 2, in <module>

    import detect as dt

ImportError: No module named detect
```

Comment: its saying, either you dont have detect.py file in your current directory or you didn't install detect library, check where you copied that code

Comment: thank you for your help i solved that problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean detect_image in darknet.py? You can check the darknet.py which have you want or not.